# MySQL JOIN condition if value in column is not null

Tags: mysql, join

### Query

```
SELECT employee.emp_number as employee_id,
employee.termination_id,
employee.firstname as user_name,
termination.termination_date 
FROM employee
JOIN user ON user.emp_number = employee.emp_number 
JOIN reportto ON reportto.emp_number = employee.emp_number 
LEFT JOIN termination ON 
( termination.id = employee.termination_id 
  AND termination.termination_date > '2016-01-01') 
WHERE ohrm_user.created_by = '31' 
GROUP BY employee.emp_number
```

### What I am trying

In the `employee` table by default `termination_id` is set `NULL`. If employee is terminated then the `id` from `termination` table is set as value. I want to get all employees who are not at all terminated or terminated before a certain date.

The above query gets all results including results with `termination_date` less than 2016-01-01. Is it possible to modify the query so that it omits the results with `termination_date` less than 2016-01-01? or do I have to execute 2 different queries and combine the result to achieve this.

***Note to avoid confusion: I want employees who are still working (not terminated) AND not terminated before 2016-01-01***

Comment: use this **termination.termination_date > '2016-01-01'** in where clause

Comment: you mean you want employees who are still working (did not terminated) OR terminated before 2016-01-01?

Comment: @SubrataDey It returns only terminated employees whose termination date >2016-01-01. Its doesn't return employees who are not terminated

Comment: @GauravLad I want employees who are still working (not terminated) AND terminated after 2016-01-01

Comment: The combination is weird, you want both in single query, 1. not terminated AND 2. terminated.
Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Try
    WHERE ohrm_user.created_by = '31' 
    AND (employee.termination_id IS NULL OR termination.termination_date >= '2016-01-01')

Comment: @GauravLad Please see Zafar Malik answer.

Comment: @GauravLad Yeah got it. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query-

```
SELECT employee.emp_number AS employee_id,
employee.termination_id,
employee.firstname AS user_name,
termination.termination_date 
FROM employee
JOIN USER ON user.emp_number = employee.emp_number 
JOIN reportto ON reportto.emp_number = employee.emp_number 
LEFT JOIN termination ON 
( termination.id = employee.termination_id ) 
WHERE ohrm_user.created_by = '31' 
AND (employee.termination_id IS NULL OR termination.termination_date >= '2016-01-01') 
GROUP BY employee.emp_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try moving the check on the `termination_date` to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT employee.emp_number as employee_id, employee.termination_id,
    employee.firstname as user_name, termination.termination_date 
FROM employee
JOIN user
    ON user.emp_number = employee.emp_number 
JOIN reportto
    ON reportto.emp_number = employee.emp_number 
LEFT JOIN termination
    ON termination.id = employee.termination_id 
WHERE (termination.termination_date IS NULL OR termination.termination_date > '2016-01-01')
    AND ohrm_user.created_by = '31'
GROUP BY employee.emp_number
```

A comment about the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (termination.termination_date IS NULL OR termination.termination_date > '2016-01-01')
```

This will first check if `termination.termination_date` be `NULL`, which would indicate an employee record which did not match the `termination` table, implying he is still working.  Second, if `termination.termination_date` be not `NULL`, then it checks that his date of termination occurred later than `2016-01-01`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the

```
AND termination.termination_date > '2016-01-01'
```

from present position to after

```
WHERE ohrm_user.created_by = '31'
```

That should do the trick